# Is it possible to fetch poolname of current running build in azure devops?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml

I have a pipeline in which I need to push the agent poolname of the current running build as a variable but couldnt find any predefined variables from azure devops.

Demo-yml-pipeline below:

```
name: $(BuildID)
trigger: none

pool: Self Hosted Docker (Linux)

steps:
- powershell: |
     Write-Host "want poolname on which the pipeline is running"
```

Thanks.

Fount Agent.name [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables-devops-services) but it is returning agentName instead of poolname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no built in way way to fetch the pool name.

I can think of two options you could use to obtain it.

---

#### Set an environment variable

If you have access to the agent, you can create an enviroment variable and reference that in your script.

In Linux, you can use `export poolName=poolValue`, and then reference it in powershell. Note that environment variables in linux are case sensitive.

```
name: $(BuildID)
trigger: none

pool: Self Hosted Docker (Linux)

steps:
- powershell: |
     Write-Host $env:poolName
```

---

#### Store it in a variable

You can define your pool name in a variable, and use that variable to reference the pool.

```
name: $(BuildID)
trigger: none

variables:
- name: poolName
  value: 'Self Hosted Docker (Linux)'

pool: $(poolName)

steps:
- powershell: |
     Write-Host $(poolName)
```